# is there a cleaner way to right operator[]() for a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, refactoring

For a vector pointer, is there a cleaner way to assign a value to an element in the vector through its pointer. For example;

`vector<int> *num = new vector<int>(10,0); //gives {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
 num->operator[](2) = 5; //gives {0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}. IS HORRIBLE CODE! HELP`

Comment: The cleanest way is to not use a pointer.

Comment: There is hardly ever (never?) a need to use a pointer for a vector.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Please don't answer in comments... certainly don't re-answer dupes. You only encourage poor behaviour...